# Prevent refreshing SelectInput while changeing data

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyjs

I have used reactiveVal for the data, I have actionbuttons where I am using for filling N/A's, Square UP values of columns etc. While using actionbuttons the selectin put is resetting and goes to its default value. How I can prevent resetting selectinput while using actionbuttons.

```
 data <- reactiveVal()

csvfinal <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$file1, ignoreNULL=T, ignoreInit=T, {
    file2 <- input$file1
    if(is.null(file2)){return()} 
    data(readr::read_delim(file=file2$datapath, delim = input$sep, col_names = input$header, show_col_types = F))
    
})



output$var_change <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(inputId = 'var_change',
                label = 'Please select an option',
                choices = as.list(names(data())),
                )
})





output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data()
    },options = list(aLengthMenu = c(10, 15, 20),scrollX = TRUE,scrollY = 900))




observeEvent(input$droper ,{
    claim <- data()
    claim <- claim[,!names(claim) %in% c(input$var_change)]
    data(claim)


})


observeEvent(input$square ,{

    req(input$var_change)
    claim <- data()
    if (is.numeric(data()[input$var_change][[1]])) {
        claim[input$var_change] <- '^'(claim[input$var_change],2)
    }
    else {
        claim[input$var_change] <- claim[input$var_change]
    }
    data(claim)
    
})


observeEvent(input$root ,{
    req(input$var_change)
    claim <- data()
    if (is.numeric(data()[input$var_change][[1]])) {
        claim[input$var_change] <- '^'(claim[input$var_change],1/2)
    }
    else {
        claim[input$var_change] <- claim[input$var_change]
    }
    data(claim)
    
})
```

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.  Based on the code you have so far, I suggest you to use `selectizeInput` on UI side and use `updateSelectInput` to update the input instead of using `renderUI`

Comment: I found the way to solve the problem. Thanks everyone, we have to change the selected into input$var_change to keep the values.